# Footer always on the boottom without display:fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css, footer, sticky

I want to make my footer display always on the bottom of the page even when the content does not fill the page, but when the content fills the page i want it to display only when i scroll to the very bottom of the page.
I was thinking to check if the page can be scrolled with JavaScript and if no I'll add a class to make footer fixed else if yes ill remove that class, but I don't know how to check that with JavaScript.
The idea is, I want my footer fixed when I cant scroll ,and when I can scroll I don't want it fixed. How can I do that ? 
My footer HTML is :

```
<footer class="smallFooter">
            <p> @EDUARDVALENTIN 2015 </p>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/danadesignsartoria?fref=ufi"><img src="img/fb-logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram-logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqe4oWvPuSP8kTL70V1P9Gg/feed"><img src="img/yt-logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/SartoriaAsti"><img src="img/twitter-logo.png" /></a>
        </footer>
```

And CSS:

```
.smallFooter{   
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;  
    position:fixed;
    height:35px;
    background-color:#0E0E0E ;

}



.smallFooter p{
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    color:white;
    font-size:10px;
    float:left;

}


footer img{
    width:25x;
    height:25px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-right:3%;
    padding-top:8px;

}
```

Comment: You could use `min-height` on your body.

Comment: add your page html including header body content and footer

Comment: Check [this](http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set min-height in your "containter" element above your footer.

```
min-height: 100%
```

Set the position of your footer as absolute.

Here is an example: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've used before is [this sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

The footer height needs to be known, and the most important pieces are the body height and wrapper with the min-height and negative margin-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Get document height and other content height like in code

```
//$(".site_wrapper").height() -> Content height which is your center warraper
//$(".header_wrapper").height() ->  header wrapper height
//$(".header_wrapper").height() -> footer warpper height
//$(".site_wrapper").height() -> your complete page's wrraper
$(document).ready(function(){
if($(document).height() > $(".site_wrapper").height()){
            var dHeight = $(document).height();
            var fHeight = $(".footer_warpper").height();
            var hHeight = $(".header_wrapper").height();
            var height = dHeight -  (fHeight + hHeight) - 50; //adjust 50 +/- according to your page
            $(".main_table").css("height",height);
        }
});
```

Comment: If this were to be used it should probably be bound to window resize, but it's also something that shouldn't require JS at all unless doing something unusually complex.

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS-only solution that doesn't depend on fixed height, use `display: table`.

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.smallFooter {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Main content goes here.</p>
</div>
<footer class="smallFooter">
    <p>Footer content goes here</p>
</footer>
```

See it in action with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmw1ehpc/)

Answer (score 0):

```
**HTML**
<div class="mydiv">
  Suspendisse potenti.
</div>

<footer class="smallFooter">
        <p> @EDUARDVALENTIN 2015 </p>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/danadesignsartoria?fref=ufi"><img src="img/fb-logo.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram-logo.png" /></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqe4oWvPuSP8kTL70V1P9Gg/feed"><img src="img/yt-logo.png" /></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/SartoriaAsti"><img src="img/twitter-logo.png" /></a>
    </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.mydiv{
    background : red;
}
.smallFooter{   
 width:100%;  
height:35px;
background-color:#0E0E0E ;
position:relative;
}



 .smallFooter p{
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:white;
font-size:10px;
float:left;

}


footer img{
width:25x;
height:25px;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin-right:3%;
padding-top:8px;

}
```

**JS**

```
$(".mydiv").css({"min-height":($("body").outerHeight()-$(".smallFooter").outerHeight())});
```

You can try something like this as well using a little bit of Jquery. Does this help? 
Have the body take full height and the remaining contents take what is left.

http://jsfiddle.net/53hf73nL/1/ when there is a lot of content
http://jsfiddle.net/53hf73nL/2/ when there is not much content.